# Converting a variadic macro to a variadic template function?

Tags: variadic-functions, variadic-templates, c++11, perfect-forwarding, variadic-macros

Given a variadic macro of the form:

```
#define MY_CALL_RETURN_F(FType, FId, ...) \
  if(/*prelude omitted*/) {             \
    FType f = (FType)GetFuncFomId(FId); \
    if(f) {                             \
      return f(__VA_ARGS__);            \
    } else {                            \
      throw invalid_function_id(FId);   \
    }                                   \
  }                                     \
/**/
```

-- how can this be rewritten to a variadic function template?

```
template<typename FType, typename ...Args>
/*return type?*/ tmpl_call_return_f(MyFunId const& FId, /*what goes here?*/)
{
  ...
  FType f = (FType)GetFuncFomId(FId);
  return f(/*what goes here?*/);
  ...
}
```

Update: I'm specifically interested in how to declare the reference type for the `Args`: `&&` or `const&` or what?

Update: Note that FType is supposed to be a "plain" function pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would look something like this:

```
template<typename FType, typename ...Args>
std::result_of<FType(Args...)>::type tmpl_call_return_f(MyFunId const& FId, Args... &&args)
{
  FType f = (FType)GetFuncFomId(FId)
  return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `std::function` as `FType`, then this should work:

```
template <typename FType, typename ...Args>
typename FType::result_type tmpl_call_return_f(MyFunId const& FId, Args... args) {
  // ...
  return f(args...);
}
```

Comment: How is `FType` going to be deduced? Or are you planning on specifying it explicitly? If so, you might as well just specify the return type...