# Issue converting a macro with variable args (...) into constexpr variadic template

Tags: c++

I tried to convert this macro based on this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161624/converting-a-variadic-macro-to-a-variadic-template-function) into a constexpr but can't get it right:

```
#define log_error(...) log_api(__FILE__, __LINE__, log_api_severity::error, /*print_console=*/false, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Here my last attempt and I am quite discouraged...

```
template<typename ...Args>
std::result_of<Args...>::type tmpl_call_return_f(Args...&& args)
{
    return log_api(__FILE__, __LINE__, log_api_severity::error, /*print_console=*/false, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

The error I got from Visual Studio 2019 is this one:

> (struct) result_of<_Fty>   in namespace std   explain usage
>
> use the 'typename' keyword to treat nontype
>   'std::result_of<_Fty>::type [with _Fty=Args...]" as a type in a
>   dependent context

I don't understand how to fix the code and what to do from there.

Below a sample that builds with Visual Studio 2019 (I commented out the constexpr and use the macro to give the context of my attempt):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>

// This is the macro I want to convert into constexpr variadic template?
#define log_error(...) log_api(__FILE__, __LINE__, log_api_severity::error, /*print_console=*/false, __VA_ARGS__)

// Error: use the 'typename' keyword to treat nontype "std::result_of<_Fty>::type[with _Fty=Args...]" as a type in a dependent context
// template<typename ...Args>
// std::result_of<Args...>::type tmpl_call_return_f(Args...&& args)
// {
//     return log_api(__FILE__, __LINE__, log_api_severity::error, /*print_console=*/false, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
// }

// Log severity levels
enum class log_api_severity
{
    error = 0,
    warning = 50,
    info = 51,
    debug = 52,
    trace = 53,
    all = 54,
    disabled = 55,
};

bool log_api(const char* filename, const int line_number, const log_api_severity severity, const bool print_console, const char* fmt, ...)
{
    char     msg[1024] = "";
    va_list  args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vsprintf_s(msg, sizeof(msg), fmt, args);

    // write in the log file...
    printf("%s", msg);

    va_end(args);
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    log_error("this is an error message");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, even if you fix the syntax, you will then discover a surprise: every call will use the same `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`, namely the file and line where the variadic template function is defined, which is obviously not what you want. You will need to wait until C++20 to do this right. For now, you have to stick to macros.

Comment: Oh that's interesting. I assume I hit a special case for which this is fine to use a macro and ignore the compiler recommendation asking me to convert it into an constexpr. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I am curious. Why is that? `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` do the expected thing with normal macros

Comment: @Ayxan because `__FILE__`  and `__LINE__`  refer to the line and file where they are located when they are replaced by the line and the file. For `#define log_error(...)` each occurrence of `log_error` is first replaced by the `log_api(__FILE__, __LINE__, ...`, so the `__FILE__`  and `__LINE__`  are acutally at the place where the `log_error(...)` appeared in the code.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Even with C++ 20, I am not sure if it could works without macros if you want variable number of arguments. I think you need default for file/line variables and default must be at the end. As variable number of arguments also need to be at the end. Or I am missing something?

Comment: @Phil1970 - the C++20 solution does not use macros, but `std::source_location`, and will work perfectly fine with variadic parameters. Look it up.

Comment: What (do you think) is “a constexpr”?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik May I ask what the C++20 feature is called that does this right?

Comment: @Sam doesn't it require template variadic arguments instead of C-style?

Comment: @DeanSeo - I mentioned this feature in my previous comment.

Comment: @JVApen - pop quiz: in my previous comment, what did I write: it does work, or it doesn't work, with variadic parameters?

Comment: @Sam: I would assume that the C variant wouldn't work, although I've never used it in real life

Comment: The compiler error message is very informative.  `std::result_of<Args...>::type` is a dependent name and you need to use `typename` before.  Other than that, `Args...&& args` should be changed to `Args&&... args`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Great. Thanks.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I mostly understand how parameter pack and `source_location` work independently. What I am not sure is if we can combine them. If we have `template<typename ...Args> void f(Args&& ... args, const std::source_location& location = std::source_location::current())` and we call it like that `f(a, b, c)`, **how would the compiler decide if `c` is in the pack or the optional argument for source location?**. That is, what are the rules to decide between an extra argument for the pack or replacing a default value?.

Comment: Sacrifice three extra characters (not including whitespace) to the gods of C++, by calling `f({}, arg1, arg2, arg3)`, declared as `template<typename ...Args> void f(const default_source_location &, Args && ...args)`. `default_source_location` is your own helper class whose constructor takes a `std::source_location` parameter with a default value of `current location`, and stashes it inside the class, and `f()` can fetch it out.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik We've discovered a way to use `source_location` with variadic templates without cluttering the caller syntax in https://stackoverflow.com/a/57548488.  It involves using the constructor of a variadic template class and a deduction guide.

Comment: I also considered this wrapping approach, @L.F., but I could not be certain whether `std::source_location` in this approach will always turn out to be the source location of the `debug` template, which will always be the same, of course, or the source location of each individual instantiation of the `debug` template. cppreference.com defines `std::source_location::current` as "corresponding to the location of the call site." To me, the `debug` template is the call site. I suspect that the observed results may vary depending on the compiler.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The deduction guide is irrelevant after the class template arguments are deduced, the constructor is called directly.  So it should work with no problem.