# Additional type in template deduction guide

Tags: c++, c++17, template-argument-deduction

This snippet demonstrates how to use deduction guides to allow `source_location::current` together with parameter packs (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57548488/1421332):

```
template <typename... Params>
struct Test
{
   Test(Params&&... params,
        const std::source_location& loc = std::source_location::current());
};

template <typename ...Params>
Test(Params&&...) -> Test<Params...>;
```

Which is used like this:

```
Test(5, 'A', 3.14f, "foo");
```

Now I want to extend the struct Test by an additional Type T that shall be specified explicitly. I tried the following but the deduction guide is not accepted:

```
template <typename T, typename... Params>
struct Test
{
    Test(Params&&... params,
         const std::source_location& loc = std::source_location::current());
};

template <typename T, typename ...Params>
Test(Params&&...) -> Test<T, Params...>;
```

Compiler says:

> deduction guide template contains a template parameter that cannot be
>   deduced.

I need the additional T to allow `struct Test` to internally build an object of a user specified type.

It should be used like this:

```
Test<MyType>(5, 'A', 3.14f, "foo");
```

Is it possible to define a deduction guide including the additional T?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do it in this syntax:

```
Test<MyType>(5, 'A', 3.14f, "foo");
```

Because there is no such thing as "partial" class template argument deduction. It's all or nothing - you either specify *all* the class template parameters or *none* of the class template parameters.

However, you can just move the type over:

```
template <typename T> struct type_t {};
template <typename T> inline type_t<T> type{};

Test(type<MyType>, 5, 'A', 3.14f, "foo");
```

And now you deduced the type. You can even write the deduction guide to require this usage:

```
template <typename T, typename ...Params>
Test(type_t<T>, Params&&...) -> Test<T, Params...>;
```

Although `Test`'s constructor still needs to take a `type_t<T>` argument first.

Comment: Since C++20 one can use `std::type_identity` so instead of your own `type_t<T>` one can use `std::type_identity<T>` and then instead of sending `type<MyType>` send `std::type_identity<MyType>{}`.