# Variadic template print implementation with separator

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to do a simple PoC with variadic templates. Right now, my code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
void println(const T& head) {
    cout << head << endl;
}

template <typename T, typename ... Args>
void println(const T& head, Args&& ... args) {
    cout << head << ", ";
    println(args...);
}

int main() {
    println(1,2,3,4,5,6);
}
```

Here, the separator is `,` , but I would like to be user provided, and also with a default value. However, trying something like `void println(const T& head, const Args&... args, const string& sep = ",")` is not going to work due the parameter pack. Is there any workaround to do this in a simple manner?

Comment: Pass the separator in the first parameter?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat a default parameter should be at the end of the list of parameters.

Comment: I'd do two different functions then, one that always uses comma, and the other one with a custom separator. Or you want this just to practice variadic templates?

Comment: If the separator is a single char... pass it as template non type parameter? Something as `template <char Sep=',', typename T, typename ... Args>`? That you can call `println<':'>(1,2,3,4,5,6);`

Comment: @max66 I thought this, but the syntaxis is really ugly... I would like to pass it as a parameter.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62216484/combining-function-parameter-pack-and-default-arguments

Answer (score 5):

I propose the following, non recursive, version. Based on a template defaulted value separator

```
#include <iostream>

template <char Sep = ',', typename T, typename ... Args>
void println (T const & head, Args const & ... args)
 { ((std::cout << head), ..., (std::cout << Sep << ' ' << args)) << std::endl; }

int main()
 {
   println(1,2,3,4,5,6);
   println<':'>(1,2,3,4,5,6);
 }
```

that prints

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
1: 2: 3: 4: 5: 6
```

Comment: Ok, now I'm lost. What's doing `...` inside the function there?

Comment: @Norhther It's a [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold).

Comment: @Norhther - It's available starting from C++17; if you use C++14 or C++11, I can simulate it in a little less elegant way.