# C++20 source_location to replace macro to multi-parameter variadic template

Tags: c++

Can this be made to display the line number of the actual call site, like the macro does ?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <source_location>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

namespace myLib{

template<typename Enumt, typename... Ts> // alert bad calls, throw
constexpr void setValsF(const unsigned line, Ts const&... args){
  cout << "line #"<<line<<": illegal call to setVals()\n";
  assert(is_enum_v<Enumt>);
}

template<class... Enumt, class = common_type_t<Enumt...> > 
requires conjunction_v<is_enum<Enumt>...>
constexpr void setValsF(const unsigned line, Enumt&... vals){
  cout << "line #"<<line<<": legal call to setVals()\n";
}
 
}// myLib

int main(){

  enum enumVals : short { a = 0, b, c, count };
  
  // #define setVals(...) myLib::setValsF<enumVals>(__LINE__ __VA_OPT__(,__VA_ARGS__))
  constexpr auto setVals = [](auto&&... args) {  
    myLib::setValsF<enumVals>(source_location::current().line(), args...); };
  
  setVals(a,b); // legal
  setVals(b,"text"); // illegal
}
```

[run](https://godbolt.org/z/o443erqxo)

.. keeping a nice simple API ( `setVals(a,b)` ), that is.

It would work :

- with a defaulted argument to the function template, but for the parameter pack. Couldn't figure a deduction guide in the presence of more than one template parameter.
- or if current() was the default constructor to source_location !

I resorted to runtime handling of bad calls (to certain APIs) as a courtesy to my library users, as my very specific insult is wayyy nicer than the indecipherable blob the compiler vomits.

Comment: The normal trick is to put the default argument into a parameter's constructor.

Comment: Yup. That's the nicest way out. Could not adapt `FormatWithLocation` from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57547273/how-to-use-source-location-in-a-variadic-template-function to my case with multiple template parameters :(

Comment: I'm not sure why you can't just use `static_assert()` if all that you want to do is to display error message...

Comment: @sklott : the first template is just a trap that hands the dead fly to a dedicated `libAlert()` with some info (depending on previous user init choices) to form a precise error message. Not sure how a `static_assert` would help with the originating line issue.

Comment: Would this: https://godbolt.org/z/GrY6njMda be enough or is it too verbose for your taste?

Comment: @Bob__ Pretty neat workaround!

Comment: @Bob__ that's brilliant ! I basically lost hope on this, and now I'm scratching my head as I jump with excitement looking at the output window. The left window though.. looks a bit above my pay-grade, would you care to explain the voodoo in an complete answer ?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm afraid that clang [doesn't agree](https://godbolt.org/z/WqY31dKcj)...

Comment: @Bob__ Hmm, clang seems to mess it up in general when `source_location` is a default argument to function templates. https://godbolt.org/z/xvxMj3esz - Edit: It doesn't matter if it's a function template. It's borked either way: https://godbolt.org/z/sd5e46bxG - and I wouldn't care about that too much. They will have to fix that bug. - Edit2: It _is_ fixed, on trunk: https://godbolt.org/z/5jj5bcP1x

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment, as requested by the OP.

[Piotr Skotnicki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3953764/piotr-skotnicki)'s [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57548488/4944425) to [How to use source_location in a variadic template function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57547273/how-to-use-source-location-in-a-variadic-template-function) introduces an helper class and a deduction guide:

> ```
> template <typename... Ts>
> struct debug
> {    
>    debug( Ts&&... ts
>         , const std::source_location& loc = >std::source_location::current());
> };
>
> // The deduction guide forces the deduction of the pack, "separating"
> // it from the default parameter.
> template <typename... Ts>
> debug(Ts&&...) -> debug<Ts...>;
>
> int main()
> {
>    debug(5, 'A', 3.14f, "foo");
> }
> ```

Here, though, something else needs to be passed. My proposal is to inject the requirements as a template parameter *before* the pack.

```
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>
#include <source_location>

template <typename R, typename... Ts>
struct debug
{    
  debug( R&& req      // <- A requirement that the pack ts must fulfill.
       , Ts&&... ts
       , std::source_location const& loc = std::source_location::current() )
  {
    std::cout << "line #" << loc.line() << ": "
              << ( req(ts...) ? "valid call\n" : "invalid call\n" );
  }
};

// We don't need to differentiate the first parameter of the pack, here.
template <typename... Args>
debug(Args&&...) -> debug<Args...>;

int main()
{
  enum enumVals : short { a = 0, b, c, count };
  
  // Since C++20 we can have templated lambdas. Here I don't need named parameters,
  // but I need named types to use std::same_as in the fold expression.
  constexpr auto all_enums = []<typename... Ts>(Ts&&...) {
    return ( ... and std::same_as<std::remove_cvref_t<Ts>, enumVals> );
  };

  debug(all_enums, a, b);   // -> line #31: valid call
  debug(all_enums, b, 1);   // -> line #32: invalid call
}
```

This is not as terse as `setVals(a,b)`, in OP's code, but seems to work<sup>1</sup> as intended.

---

<sup>1) Note that this works with gcc and clang(trunk) (as noted by Ted Lyngmo), but not with clang15: https://godbolt.org/z/zxxMTs4Kj</sup>

Comment: Thank you, I'm learning from this. First time I see a unary left fold in the wild. I'm amazed that you can pass a closure not by argument, but by *template argument* & not only save a `std::invoke`, but also an ugly `.operator()` call ! This also elegantly transmits only types to the `source_location`-instantiating object thus completely eliding the issue of copying an argument of a type 10k x 10k matrix just to tell the user he passed the wrong one ! Brilliant.

Comment: Still can't move this closer to target (transparent API call), example : https://godbolt.org/z/56qzd74Gb

Comment: @ExpertNoob1 Yeah, sorry, I can't think of anything better.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry for. I don't think C++20 `source_location` can do this, honestly. Nothing wrong with `__LINE__`. I already used what I learned from you to reduce the arg checking code by 50% :  my API is now single instance taking a universal `Ts...` squeezed through `(... and checkArg.operator()<Is>());` (`Is` = seq. `0 .. sizeof...(Ts)-1`) : much smaller, clearer, nicer, self contained <cool dude emoji>