# How to perfect forward variadic template args with default argument std::source_location?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding

I want to track where the creation of an object occurs using `std::source_location`. The following is a simplified example without the extra code to account for copy and movement of a `Tracked` object.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <source_location>

template <typename Underlying>
struct Tracked 
{
    Underlying val;
    std::source_location loc;
};

template <typename Underlying, typename T>
auto makeTracked(T&& t, std::source_location loc = std::source_location::current()) 
{
    // make_unique is a simplification, the actual code uses something more complicated
    // the important thing is that there is an extra function call here
    return std::make_unique<Tracked<Underlying>>(Underlying{ std::forward<T>(t) }, std::move(loc));
}

int main() 
{
    auto p = makeTracked<std::string>("abc");
    std::cout << p->val << "@" << p->loc.line() << std::endl;
    // Expected usage:
    // auto p1 = makeTracked<std::tuple<int, int, int>>(3, 4, 5);
}
```

The code currently [works](https://godbolt.org/z/583o558zG), but only for types whose constructor takes exactly one parameter. I want to change `makeTracked` to be variadic, but then it conflicts with the default argument for `loc`.

I have checked the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57547273/how-to-use-source-location-in-a-variadic-template-function), and none of the answers solve my issue completely.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57548488/3966456) changes the function to a struct, which is fine in the original question because we don't care about the type of the return value (it is `void` in the original question), but that is not the case here. Even if we were fine with the return type being a `makeTracked` object instead of a `unique_ptr`, the problem still arises as how to specify the `Underlying` template parameter as the original answer uses deduction guide, and we can't have partial deduction guides that only deduce the `T` (or `Ts...` in the expected usage) but still allow us to specify the `Underlying` explicitly.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66402319/3966456) requires that you know the type of the first argument (it cannot be deduced), which does not apply here.

The first alternative in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57547898/3966456) that manually expands all the cases for `0 argument`, `1 argument`, `2 arguments...` is actually closest to what is working, however it requires that we know the maximal number of arguments in advance.

Is there a way to make the commented out part of "**Expected usage**" work for an arbitrary number of arguments, which also perfectly forwards all the arguments?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why @JeJo brought concepts into his answer. Here is a slightly less verbose solution:

```
template<typename Underlying>
struct MakeTracked {
    std::source_location loc = std::source_location::current();

    template<typename... Args>
    constexpr auto operator()(Args&&... args) const {
        return std::make_unique<Tracked<Underlying>>(
            Underlying{ std::forward<Args>(args)... },
            loc
        );
    }
};

// ...

auto p1 = MakeTracked<std::tuple<int, int, int>>{}(3, 4, 5);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YTGE764q3)

Comment: Oh, nice. How did I miss the obvious one! I was blindly over-thinking and came up with over-engineering. +1.

Comment: This is a good solution. Unfortunately some programmers will twist themselves into knots trying to find a way to avoid the need for the extra braces, instead of doing real work.

Comment: @BrianBi What do you mean by that? Can we do without the extra {}?

Comment: @LernerCpp I have no idea, but I'm sure someone will try.

Answer (score 9):

> I want to change `makeTracked` to be variadic, but then it conflicts with the default argument for `loc`.

You can maybe provide, two step function call using functors:

```
#include <concepts>  // std::convertible_to

template<typename T = std::source_location> 
    requires std::convertible_to<T, std::source_location>
struct MakeTracked 
{
    T loc{ std::source_location::current() };

    template <typename Underlying, typename... Args>
    constexpr auto operator()(Args&&... args) const
    {
        return std::make_unique<Tracked<Underlying>>(
            Underlying{ std::forward<Args>(args)... },
            loc
        );
    }
};
```

You would call it (a bit verbosely):

```
auto p1 = MakeTracked<>{}.operator()<std::tuple<int, int, int>>(3, 4, 5);
```

[See a live demo in godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/Wh683PsbW)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I had something similar in mind but haven't tried actually implementing it because as you said, it makes the call a bit more verbose. Anyway, I will wait for some more time and if no one comes up with a way that avoids the verbosity, I will accept your answer.