# Logging alternatives/solutions in a constexpr context

Tags: c++, logging, constexpr

Currently, about 90% of my existing code is constexpr.
Which raises the question how I can add a decent logging functionality to said code.

Currently, I have the following logging code:

```cpp
#define log(fmt, ...)                                                                       \
if !consteval                                                                               \
    {                                                                                       \
      my_logger(("%s [file: %s, Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __FILE__,             \
             __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);                                                      \
    }
```

my_logger is, of course not constexpr, my question is therefore: are there any alternatives to logging in general in a constexpr context? What are best-practices in this regard?

Comment: Use a (variadic) function template to use `if consteval`.

Comment: but then I cannot use `__FILE__` nor `__PRETTY_FUNCTION___`, can I?

Comment: @johnworchester [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) (But then you will have a pretty hard time prepending `"%s [file: %s, Line %d] "` to the format string)

Comment: For older C++ you can still mix things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still combine macro + variadic template function. Demo : https://onlinegdb.com/Ak6D55MPt

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr bool enable_logging = true;

template<typename arg_t, typename... args_t>
void log(const char* file, long line, arg_t&& arg, args_t&&... args)
{
    if constexpr (enable_logging)
    {
        std::cout << file << "(" << line << ") : " << std::forward<arg_t>(arg);
        // fold expression
        ((std::cout << ", " << std::forward<args_t>(args)),...);
    }
}

#define LOG(...) log(__FILE__,__LINE__,__VA_ARGS__);

int main()
{
    LOG("hello", 1, 2, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See [how-to-use-source-location-in-a-variadic-template-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57547273/how-to-use-source-location-in-a-variadic-template-function) to even avoid MACRO.

Comment: @Jarod42 I know, I don't like macros so much either. This is just a C++17 demo