# How to get the name of an invoked function instead of getting the caller functions name in c++

Tags: c++

I am attempting to create a function which takes in a function as a param and the functions required params to pass to it, the purpose of this function is to print out the function we have been passed in our params. Problem is, when i use something like `__func__` we all know this returns the calling function name. My idea is to make the function im parsing the subject of the matter and retrieve its name. This is what i have so far...

```cpp
    template <typename F, typename... Args>
    void LogCalledFunction(F f, Args ... args)
    {
        //get invoked function name
        //print invoked function name
        //call invoked function
        std::invoke(f, args...);
    }
```

the purpose of this is to make a better debugging method because i will have an if statement to check for a global var to see if it should run, making it an instant and easier debug method as sometimes stack call hurts my brain.

Any help is **VERY** much appreciated. I have been trying to find a solution for 2-3 days.
Thank you!

Comment: [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) might help. `__func__` no longer needed.

Comment: See [how-to-use-source-location-in-a-variadic-template-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57547273/how-to-use-source-location-in-a-variadic-template-function).

Comment: Although macros are not in the spirit of modern C++, but I would suggest a macro because: (1) it will work (2) it won't significantly increase compile times to resolve all the templates for all the functions (3) can be disabled for release builds with removing all overhead, while template may still have overhead of calling the wrapper function

Comment: To make sure I understand: you need the name of the function passed as `f`, **not** the name of the function that calls `LogCalledFunction`, right ?

Comment: Unlike Python, C++ functions don't carry their names around. If you need it, you need to associate functions and names yourself.

Comment: @user12002570 are you sure the duplicate is relevant ? the OP didn't answer my comment question above, but I suspect they need the name for `f` (or rather the argument passed for `f`), not for the caller of `LogCalledFunction` (which is what the duplicate is about if I understood correctly).

Comment: @wohlstad OP can ping me, I'll reopen.

Comment: If it is like @wohlstad think, that you want the name of the function you pass as `f`, then remember that there are sometimes functions that doesn't have a name. That aren't actually a *function*. Think about objects with an overloaded function-call operator, what is the "name" of the function then? The name of the object? Or `operator()`? Or `classname::operator()`? And what about anonymous lambdas? Where your function is called as `LogCalledFunction([](args) { /* ... */ }, ...)`, what is the "name" then?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude all the things you wrote make sense, and could probably be the answer to the question as I understood it. BTW - I based my understanding on the question text: _"print out the function we have been passed in our params"_ and also on the comments in the OP's code: _"print invoked function name"_ and _"call invoked function"_ - both seems to relate to what was passed as `f`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to C++20 and [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location), then unfortunately the solution might have to involve macros, and an update to your function to accept the function name as a string.

Perhaps something like this:

```
#define LogCalledFunction(f, ...) RealLogCalledFunction(__func__, f, __VA_ARGS__)

template <typename F, typename... Args>
void RealLogCalledFunction(std::string const& name, F f, Args ... args)
{
    // ...
}
```

As mentioned in a comment, it's also very easy to disable all logging completely by using a macro, as then you could conditionally make the macro expand to an empty statement which does nothing and will be optimized away by the compiler (like a `do { } while (false)` loop).

Comment: This is super great thank you so much, but my good sir, i am exactly on C++20 and i do use std::source_location but the problem is, i use std::source_location::current() which gets my current function, which in this case would be realLogCalledFunction, not the function it is calling. So am i wrong with what im saying, i'd love to hear your thoughts. i'd like to steer clear from macros as they almost make it, too easy? if you understand when im coming from. But if push come to shove, i will use that as it is  effective as you said.

Comment: @user17096148 Please see [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57547273/how-to-use-source-location-in-a-variadic-template-function) that Jarod42 linked to in a comment.